# No corre el if en mi codigo

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de la facultad y me encuentro trancado hace rato en un problema, cuando corro el codigo no me toma la condicion que establecí con el if.

La idea es que cuando se seleccione el tipo de viajero "plus" el valor ingresado en el primer input sea multiplicado por dos.
No me estoy dando cuenta del problema que seguramente para muchos sea una pequeñez...

Cualquier ayuda se agradece!
Dejo el codigo

```js
window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);

function onLoad(){
    console.log("cargó");

    const send = document.querySelector("#send");
    send.addEventListener("click", onSend);

}

function onSend(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    const inputMillas = document.querySelector("#inputMillas");
    const viajero = document.querySelector("#viajero");
    
    const pMsje = document.querySelector("#pMsje");
    pMsje.innerHTML = "";

    let resultado = Number(inputMillas.value);
    let Europa = resultado >= 60000;
    let America_del_norte = resultado >= 30000 && resultado < 60000;
    let America_del_sur = resultado >= 15000 && resultado < 30000;
    let insuficiente = resultado < 15000;
    let Destino = Europa || America_del_norte || America_del_sur || insuficiente;

    
    if(viajero.value == "plus"){
        resultado = (resultado)*2;
        
    }
    

    switch(Destino){
        case insuficiente:
            pMsje.innerHTML = "No tiene millas suficientes";
            break;
        
        case America_del_sur:
            pMsje.innerHTML = "Puede viajar a cualquier destino de America del Sur";
            break;
        case America_del_norte:
            pMsje.innerHTML = "Puede viajar a cualquier destino de America del Norte";
            break;
        case Europa:
            pMsje.innerHTML = "Puede viajar a cualquier destino de Europa";
            break;
        default:
            pMsje.innerHTML = "Debe seleccionar un tipo de viajero";
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<form> 
    <label for="inputMillas">Ingrese sus millas:</label> 
    <input id="inputMillas" type="text"> <br />
    <p>Indique el tipo de viajero que es usted</p> <br /> 
    <select id="viajero">
        <option value="frecuente">Viajero frecuente</option>
        <option value="plus">Viajero Plus</option>
    </select> <br /> <br /> 
    <button id="send">Enviar</button> <br /> <br />
    <p id="pMsje"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Multiplicas por 2 pero nunca modificas el valor del input

Comment: Christian está en lo correcto. Faltaría `inputMillas.value = resultado` dentro del if

Comment: Buenas! Primero que nada gracias por responderme. Modifique como me dicen pero continuo en lo mismo. Así deje el if:

if(viajero.value == "plus"){

        
        resultado = Number(inputMillas.value)*2;
        
    }

Comment: añade el html para ver que valores tiene el campo `#viajero`

Comment: ¡Los comentarios no son para código! Debés [edit] tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @Diego.js No Diego. No era así. Voy a agregar una respuesta con el código.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo buscas es obtener el elemento por su id

```
var viajero = document.getElementById('viajero');
```

y luego su valor:

```
var viajerovalue = viajero.options[viajero.selectedIndex].Value;
```

Sustituye esa variable en el bloque if

Answer (score 0):

Faltó modificar el valor del input dentro del if:

```
if(viajero.value == "plus"){
    resultado = (resultado)*2;
    inputMillas.value = resultado;

    //O mejor todavía:
    inputMillas.value = resultado * 2;
    //Puesto que no se ve que uses la variable resultado después del if
}
```